# Hologram is not shown in the hololens 2 while it's working in the desktop

Tags: c#, windows-mixed-reality

I deploy my HoloLens 2 in Visual Studio through Release, ARM64, and Device. If I use the Release Machine instead of the Device, I got an error.
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

My desktop doesn't have the same Wi-Fi as my HoloLens. I can't connect my desktop and HoloLens to the same Wi-Fi.
My deploy is succeeded after I use the Device. My project Icon is shown in the HoloLens 2. But after I open the Icon, I can't see anything.

Please help me to find the solution. I spend a lot of time on this problem.

Comment: Does “**Release Machine**” mean “**Remote Machine**”? To be clear, Remote Machine option is used to deploy project when the computer and HoloLens are under the same WIFI network. You may refer to [Remote connection session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-visual-studio?tabs=hl2#remote-connection) to browse devices under the same network.

Comment: And **Device** option is simply deploying app via USB. If the driver is not installed on the computer, you will need to use **Remote Machine** option even the device is connected via USB. For more details, please refer to [Using Visual Studio to deploy and debug - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-visual-studio?tabs=hl2).

Comment: For this app, have you tried [remote debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/preview-and-debug-your-app?tabs=openxr) before deploying, does it work? And has the scene been added to the **Build Settings-> Scenes in Build**? Also, you can try to deploy official examples to do some tests, such as the example in the **Mixed Reality Toolkit Examples** package.

Comment: yes, It's the remote machine I misspelled it.

Comment: I tried everything that you suggest. But now also I can't see the objects in my hololens 2. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: I would like to confirm that you have tried the official sample, but it doesn't work, you can't see objects in HoloLens 2 even in remote debugging mode, right? What is your development environment? Do you have referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/new-openxr-project-with-mrtk to correctly configure the project? Is there any error message when the project is running? Any screenshots will be helpful.

Comment: yes, I followed the all steps given in that link. It doesn't work on my Hololens 2. I can't debug in the mode of the remote machine. The error appears every time I try to deploy.

Comment: The error is "BootstrapForDebugging returned null instead of IPAddress & PortNumber of the msvsmon process".     "dep6957: failed to connect to device '192.168.123.181' using universal authentication. please verify the correct remote authentication mode is specified in the project debug settings. COMException - a connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (exception from hresult: 0x8007274c) [0x8007274c]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution to my problem. Before I used the unity 2020.3.9. Now I changed the version to 2020.3.4. Now I can deploy and see the game objects in my hololens 2.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my explanation of **Remote Machine** and **Device** gave you some misunderstanding. I'm sorry about that. [**Remote Machine + WIFI** and **Device + USB**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-visual-studio?tabs=hl2#build-configuration) are both officially recommended deployment methods. Since you have successfully deployed through Device, please continue to use it. If you are still a little confused about deployment you can publish a new thread.

It seems the main issue here is that when you run the deployed project, you cannot see any object. I recommend you try **Remote Debugging**(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/preview-and-debug-your-app?tabs=openxr) in the Unity editor, which allows you to quickly preview and debug your project without deployment, and it can also be connected via **USB**. You can also use the official sample to **Remote Debugging** or deploy directly. Also, it's important to note that before you build your project in Unity, you need to add the scene to **Build Settings->Scenes in Build**.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before. In the unity editor, I can see my models normally. But the models were not shown in Hololens, or only by one eye. The reason was that the models use the standard shader of Unity. After I applied the Mixed Reality Toolkit/ Standard Shaders, every model was shown.